# How to set Chromium Proxy in 14.04?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, proxy, browser

Every guide I find online tells me to set the proxy through the Properties window of Chromium. However, when I try to right-click on the Chromium shortcut, I don't see a 'Properties' option. I'm running 14.04 Ubuntu.

Comment: Inside the Chromium itself you have a menu, click it and then something like preferences or settings

Comment: That takes me to Chromium's settings. The settings has a Network Proxy section, but that is just a text block that tells me to boot Chromium using the command line interface. If I want to boot it using the GUI, I should be able to set the properties somehow. [This guide](http://digitizor.com/2010/03/23/set-proxy-google-chrome-separately/) show what Properties I'm looking for, but I can't seem to access it.

Comment: Chromium uses your system's proxy settings, but there might be a button inside the Settings that opens up the proxy settings window.

Comment: There isn't, and I tried setting a system-wide proxy using the Network Settings window on Ubuntu. It did not affect Chromium.

Comment: I have the same problem. Why was this question downvoted?

Comment: @mardy I'm not sure but thanks for upvoting it! I found an acceptable workaround which I've posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential work around is to use Chromium on a proxy-free network to download an extension called "Proxy Helper". This will set Proxy Settings for you on Chromium.